# TypeError: Cannot read property 'calls' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to write a unit test for my store in react application.
Unit test looks like:

```
import FRIENDS from '../../constants/friends';
import FriendsStore from '../friends_store';

jest.dontMock('../../constants/friends');
jest.dontMock('../friends_store');

describe('FriendsStore', () => {

    let AppDispatcher;
    let callback;

    let addFriends = {
        actionType: FRIENDS.ADD_FRIENDS,
        name: 'Many'
    };

    let removeFriend = {
        actionType: FRIENDS.REMOVE_FRIENDS,
        id: '3'
    };

    beforeEach(function () {
        AppDispatcher = require('../../dispatcher/app_dispatcher');
        callback = AppDispatcher.register.mock.calls[0][0];
    });

    it('Should initialize with no friends items', function () {
        var all = FriendsStore.getAll();
        expect(all).toEqual([]);
    });


});
```

And when I executed with `jest` statement, I've got the error message:

```
Using Jest CLI v0.4.0
 FAIL  scripts/stores/__tests__/friends_store-test.js (0.811s)
● FriendsStore › it Should initialize with no friends items
  - TypeError: Cannot read property 'calls' of undefined
        at Spec.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Developer/reactjs/app5/scripts/stores/__tests__/friends_store-test.js:33:41)
        at jasmine.Block.execute (/Volumes/Developer/reactjs/app5/node_modules/jest-cli/vendor/jasmine/jasmine-1.3.0.js:1065:17)
        at jasmine.Queue.next_ (/Volumes/Developer/reactjs/app5/node_modules/jest-cli/vendor/jasmine/jasmine-1.3.0.js:2098:31)
        at null._onTimeout (/Volumes/Developer/reactjs/app5/node_modules/jest-cli/vendor/jasmine/jasmine-1.3.0.js:2088:18)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
1 test failed, 0 tests passed (1 total)
Run time: 1.028s
```

It seems to be, that jest can not find the `calls` property. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: actually it means that mock is undefined, and undefined doesn't have the calls property as you are expecting in beforeEach... So, you probably didn't define a mock yet when the code reaches this statement?

Comment: But I don't have to define a mock, jest do that for me automatically not? I  look at the example on https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/react, it does not define mock too.

Comment: This is one of the major confusions with using Jest. It doesn't auto mock everything you require but rather the dependencies of the stuff you require.

Comment: When I downloaded the todo mvc and test with jest, it works like a charm. But when I am trying to build the test by myself, its show me always that the property calls does not exists, it is so weird.
I am using babel to transcompile the es6 to es5 code, maybe is this the problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: suffering the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.

Making the following change should resolve the issue:

```
beforeEach(function () {
   AppDispatcher = require('../../dispatcher/app_dispatcher');
   FriendsStore = require('/path/to/store'); //**load in store**
   callback = AppDispatcher.register.mock.calls[0][0];
});
```

Working with ReactJS v15.2.1 & Jest v14.0.0
This also worked on ReactJS v14 too.

Comment: This gives me cannot read property 'mock' of undefined. What version of flux and jest did this work on?